# integral stable conjugacy classes

Tags: rt.representation-theory, matrices, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, etale-cohomology

Let $G$ be a semisimple simply connected group over $k$ algebraically closed field .

Let $\gamma,\gamma'\in G(k[[\pi]])$ that are generically regular semisimple on $G(k((\pi)))$.

We assume that there exists $g\in G(k[[\pi^{1/n}]])$ such that:

$\gamma=g\gamma'g^{-1}$

with $n$ prime to the characteristic of $k$.

Do we have that $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ are conjugated over $G(k[[\pi]])$?

Comment: The notation gets confusing, since you use $k$ for two different things.   Also, it's unclear precisely what you mean by "generically regular semisimple" here.   And is $\pi$ an indeterminate over $k$?

Comment: I only use $k$ for the base field. If you prefer you have $F=k((\pi))$ the field of Laurent series and $\mathcal{O}=k[[\pi]]$ his ring of integers.

Comment: I mean that $\gamma\in G(F)^{rs}$ so on $F$ the centralizer of $\gamma$ is a maximal torus.